# import python modules failed...what am I missing?

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I have a question about importing my own python modules from a package I wrote.

I am using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

According to

1. [setup.py manual](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html)
2. [install python](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/installing_python.html)

Assuming I have a package called **mape_misc** under catkin_ws/src,

the structure of it is :

```
src/mape_misc/
├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── package.xml
    ├── setup.py
    └── src
        └── mape_misc
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── MAPEopcode.py
```

I wanted to import mape_misc.MAPEopcode in another python packages. Supposing there is a `class OPCODE`  in `MAPEopcode.py`

However, in the other package, I got

```
from mape_misc.MAPEopcode import OPCODE
ImportError: No module named mape_misc.MAPEopcode
```

I'm stuck here right now, the content of my setup.py is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

setup_args = generate_distutils_setup(
    package=['mape_misc'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
)

setup(**setup_args)
```

In `mape_misc`, `CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(mape_misc)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
)
catkin_python_setup()

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS rospy
)
```

I don't think I need to have a `install()` because I just want to use modules.

In MAPEopcode I just defined a Enum.

I've tried to clean the build and redo catkin_make, but still no luck.

Thanks for any advice!

Edit 1: I thought for any correct import, `catkin_ws/src/mape_misc/src` should be in `PYTHONPATH`. However, after  I built everything and `source devel/setup.bash`, `echo $PYTHONPATH` showed only:
`/home/xbot/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/xbot/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269701/import-python-modules-failed...what-am-i-missing?/) by [mutantRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29573/mutantrobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK I finally found the problem ------- a really stupid mistake in setup.py, which should contain:

```
packages = ['xxxx']
```

not

```
package = ['xxxx']
```

Now everything is working.

---

Originally posted by [mutantRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/29573/mutantrobot/) with karma: 21 on 2017-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1